# When plugging in iPhone, iTunes and iPhoto open on my Mac

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos.app, apple-id

So, I've seen [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123985/disable-automatic-itunes-launch-when-iphone-is-plugged-in-via-usb) and tried to follow it... but it happens regardless. And to top it all off, iTunes gives me a grave warning now everytime I plugin my phone "if you do not authorize this computer, 22 apps, including “AccuWeather”, and their data will be deleted from this iPhone."

My Mac is using a different apple ID than my phone because my Mac is my work machine, but my phone is personal. I think this has something to do with it. I need to plugin my iPhone to my Mac to use for development (ie, testing apps and such) but I don't need to manage anything else through it.

How can I get the constant barrage of apps and now warnings/potential of lose of data from popping up each time I plug my iPhone into my Mac?

My Mac is using Yosemite and my iPhone iOS 8.3.. Everything is up to date

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a little [script](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/873-tip-prevent-iphoto-from-opening-when-you-plug-in-your-iphone) that prevents iPhoto from lunching automatically.

Just to make sure I got your question: you want to disable auto lunch for iTunes and Photos app + Disable auto sync in iTunes. Am I right?

Comment: I did disable auto-sync, but because I never authorized this computer I guess it doesn't save the setting or something because it always opens up iTunes afterwards and the auto-sync option is always enabled