# How to disable iTunes (sudo chmod no longer works)

Tags: itunes

I used to be able to disable iTunes by:

```
$ chmod -x /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
```

But then apple made it harder:

```
$ sudo chmod -x /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
chmod: Unable to change file mode on iTunes: Operation not permitted
```

My objection is: Apple starts iTunes automatically, if opened and not signed in (with the sign-in dialog up) it blocks restarting (I have to force kill it) and when XCode updates, iTunes needs to be closed and it also isn't able to exit, and I have to force-quit again.

I don't know how Apple is able to deny the "sudo chmod"

I'm looking for ways that still allow me to run it when I need to.

Comment: "Apple starts iTunes automatically" …under what circumstances? Mine never does, mainly because I told it not to.

Comment: There is no circumstance. I don't have "Open at Login" checked. It just starts on its own.

Comment: At login? Please be clear. This is not 'normal' behaviour, so to get to the root of it, we need to know precise details.

Comment: So I found a scenario where it happens - when I plug an iPhone in. I realize it may be an unusual request. Aside from that, there are times where it opens and I don't know why. I'll just be working and I'll be prompted to log in.

Comment: @Tetsujin This also happens to me whenever I plug my headphones into my iMac.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123985/disable-automatic-itunes-launch-when-iphone-is-plugged-in-via-usb